# Combinations from selecting four numbers from the set of the first eight positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Four numbers are to be selected from the set of the first eight positive integers. Find how many possible combinations there are if:
there is atleast one odd number

Now, you could do this the manual hard way taking cases so
(4C1*4C3) + (4C2*4C2) + (4C3*4C1) = 68
Or you could calculate the possible combinations for all numbers to be even:
Thats' clearly only one combination
Then subtract these from all possible combinations without restriction
8C4 -1 = 70-1 = 69

What sily thing am I doing wrong here? Why do the answers vary?

Comment: You have forgotten the case (in your first version) where all four numbers are oddd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version, you have forgotten the case where all four numbers are odd.